# Can't get input prompt after incorrect input

Tags: java, loops, exception, server, client

I'm writing a client/server guessing game right now.

I have a guessGameServerHandler class, which handles a single instance of a game for a client (the game is multi threaded)

I also have a client class reading in input, then the handler responding.

I need to output an error if the user enters in a string instead of an integer, then loop back and ask for input again, but can't seem to get it working. Any suggestions?

Client Code: (this is in a do while loop, checking if input equals correct number or not)

```
// Read in clients input
        System.out.print("Enter guess: ");

          guess = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());


        // send guess to server
        out.write(String.format("%s%n", guess));
        out.flush();
```

guessGameHandlerServer:

```
do {
          try{
          // Read in guesses from user
          guess = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
          }catch(NumberFormatException e){
          }

        gs.guess(guess);
        String timeForm = decFor.format(gs.getTimeRemaining() / 1000D);
        // Check user input against target number & time left
        if (gs.getTimeRemaining() < 1) {
          System.out.println(ID + " - (LOSE)" + timeForm + "/" + gs.getGuesses());
          client.close();
        } else if (gs.getTimeRemaining() > 0 && guess > gs.getTarget() && guess < maxNum) {
          out.write(String.format("HIGH:%s:%d%n", timeForm, gs.getGuesses()));
          out.flush();
          System.out.println(ID + " " + guess + "(HIGH)-" + timeForm + "s/" + gs.getGuesses());
        } else if (gs.getTimeRemaining() > 0 && (guess < gs.getTarget() && guess > 0)) {
          out.write(String.format("LOW:%s:%d%n", timeForm, gs.getGuesses()));
          out.flush();
          System.out.println(ID + " " + guess + "(LOW)-" + timeForm + "s/" + gs.getGuesses());
        } else if (gs.getTimeRemaining() > 0 && guess == gs.getTarget()) {
          out.write(String.format("WIN:%d%n", gs.getGuesses()));
          out.flush();
          System.out.println(ID + " " + guess + "(WIN)-" + timeForm + "s/" + gs.getGuesses());
        } else if (gs.getTimeRemaining() > 0 && (guess >= maxNum || guess < 1)) {
          out.write(String.format("ERR:%d%n", gs.getGuesses()));
          out.flush();
          System.out.println(ID + " ** (ERR out of range)" + timeForm + "/" + gs.getGuesses());
        }


      } while (true);
```

**with the current code, entering a string just makes the client thread close, no idea why.**

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception at the client side like this:

```
while(true) {
    try {
       System.out.print("Enter guess: ");

      guess = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
      break;
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
    }
}
    // send guess to server
    out.write(String.format("%s%n", guess));
    out.flush();
```

Comment: this works, but I'm also trying to send a message to the server when the client puts an incorrect input. Putting the 'out.write' within the catch block doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What do you want to send to the server when the user enters an incorrect input? You cannot send "guess" for sure, as it does not have a value due to incorrect user input. Whatever you want to send in this case, put it in the "catch" block followed by "flush". It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a try catch block in do while loop to catch the NumberFormatException.

```
    try{
       System.out.print("Enter guess: ");

       guess = Integer.parseInt(stdin.readLine());
    }catch(NumberFormatException ne){
     //exception handling - set the do while loop condition to true so that it is called again
    }


    // send guess to server
    out.write(String.format("%s%n", guess));
    out.flush();
```